# String with smiley and german or french text

Tags: ios, nsstring, utf8-decode

I have tried this code

```
const char *jsonString = [challange.description UTF8String];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:strlen(jsonString)];
    NSString *goodMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

problem is that when i m converting some special character like german "test-ö" with smiley it's not converting from above code which i have posted in above link. if i m using the same with english and smiley it's working fine. please if anyone had with same problem help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you get a UTF-8 string from the `NSString` and then convert it to an `NSData`, using an unspecified encoding (I suspect it's UTF-8, so that's OK) and then create another `NSString` object using the `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`.

Avoid all the code you have posted and simply use `challenge.description` directly.

Comment: Problem is when i m posting in server suing Afnetworking i m getting this data from the server and storing in challange model.

Comment: @Mohit I don't understand why you posted that code in your question then?

Comment: I m using this code to send over server and using the same code for diaplaying when retrieve from server.

Comment: @Mohit Sorry I don't understand what you mean.  The code you posted is redundant.  I can only comment on code you post and if the issue is in other code then I cannot help without seeing it.